# Use PullToRefresh with UITableView in Android

Tags: java, android, uitableview, listview

I try to use [Pull-to-Refresh by Chrisbanes](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) and [android-uitableview by thiagolocatelli](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview).

Because all of them extends LinearLayout. So i try to change:

```
UITableView extends PullToRefreshListView
```

The problem is:

- I cannot pull my UITableView

[image]

- Because layout of UITableView and PullToRefreshListView are LinearLayout. How can i change my layout like this:

[image]

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**
Base on Chrisbanes's answer , i have my layout

```
<com.mypacket.widget.PullToRefreshScrollView
            android:id="@+id/observable_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.mypacket.widget.UITableView
                android:id="@+id/tableView"
                style="@style/UITableView" />
        </com.mypacket.widget.PullToRefreshScrollView>
```

And my code:

```
mObservableScrollView = (PullToRefreshScrollView) findViewById(R.id.observable_scroll_view);
mTableView = (UITableView) findViewById(R.id.tableView);

        // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
        mObservableScrollView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ScrollView>() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ScrollView> refreshView) {
                new GetDataTask().execute();
            }
        });

        mObservableScrollView.setMode(Mode.PULL_UP_TO_REFRESH);
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Simulates a background job.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Log.i(TAG, "REFRESHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
            mObservableScrollView.onRefreshComplete();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

But nothing changes, i cannot scroll, cannot pull

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview/issues/7#issuecomment-7069765?

Comment: Hi, this is my old question :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently added PullToRefreshScrollView which should help you here. Just replace your ScrollView with PullToRefreshScrollView.

PullToRefreshScrollView is in the dev branch for now, but will be in master for next release.

Comment: Try again using v1.3.3 which I released yesterday. Should fix it.